# iOS Background Image doesn't display properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, uiimageview

I've literally piled through hundreds go searches on google :(. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong when I create an image in photoshop (960 x 600, -40 for the status bar). The image comes out to this:

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

(note this is not the actually size, crappy thumbnail version :P. The size is as stated above)

This is my code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuBkground.png"]];
```

Am I doing something wrong when I make the image? Is it in the code? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You're using `colorWithPatternImage` which basically means what it says. The image will repeat itself if the space is not entirely consumed by the image. If you want to have a true background image you should create the image as a subview.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuBKground.png"];
UIImageView* background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage: image];
[self.view addSubview: background];
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way if your using interface builder,

1. Drag an `image view` to your viewController.
2. Assign that as `MenuBkground.png` in the inspector (first drop down box)

Comment: Did you mean `MenuBkground.png`?